# Disabling NAT and DHCP on OpenWRT routed client router

Tags: wireless-networking, wireless-router, wireless-access-point, openwrt, wireless-bridge

i haven ADSL router (Rouer A) which provides Internet connectivity. Then i have an OpenWRT Router (Router B) wirelessly connected to Router A as "Routed Client" as explained here https://wiki.openwrt.org/doc/howto/clientmode. Also, another ADSL router configured as bridge AP (Router C) is connected to Router B via ethernet cable and also provides WiFi connectivity via ExtWiFi SSID. Lastly, i have another OpenWRT router (Router D) also configured as Routed Client and wirelessly connected to Router C through ExtWiFi SSID.

Router A is on 192.168.1.0/24 network. DHCP is enabled.
Router B configured as Routed Client is on 192.168.2.0/24 network. NAT and DHCP are enabled.
Router C acting as Bridged AP is on 192.168.2.0/24 network. NAT and DHCP are disabled.
Router D configured as Routed Client is on 192.168.3.0/24 network. NAT and DHCP are enabled.

The thing is i'm looking to this docs https://wiki.openwrt.org/doc/howto/clientmode#routed looking to different setups so i can wirelessly connect Router D to Router C while disabling NAT and DHCP on Router D so it could also belong to 192.168.2.0/24 network.

So i'm wondering, does anyone know how to setup Router D so it can be wirelessly connected to Router D while disabling NAT and forwarding DHCP requests to Router B? I would like to be able to transparently reach computers connected to Router B and Router D and vice versa.

Thanks

Comment: Even if you disable NAT, it’s still routed. For the local network of router D to be *on the same broadcast domain* as router A’s local network, you’d need a tunnel.

Comment: Hi, i would like Router D to be on the same broadcast domain as router B, not on router A domain. Could you please give more details about the tunneling yoou're talking about? OpenWRT docs talk about static routing form one network to another, i'm not sure if that's the same you're talking about. Thx!

Comment: Oh, my mistake. Still, because WiFi networks cannot be bridged, you are in a tricky situation. I suggest you first check if you can get WDS to work because that would *just work*™. Tunneling is quite complicated because of routing conflicts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally i just fixed the issue by following these instructions  https://wiki.openwrt.org/doc/howto/clientmode#routed

Basically it sums up to define a static route and accept incoming wan traffic.